# query result array, each row's column field to string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using CodeIgniter and I wrote the following code in one of my model (.php file) to do `preg_split` operation on one column value for each rows matching the query.

For context, I have no idea how to do debugging such backend operation and am lost / afraid of blowing up the database. The problem is I don't know if I'm doing the `preg_split` operation on a string or an array value.

The field type for fruits column is `varchar(32)` which is a string, but would calling `$row['fruits']` really return a pure string?

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
    //  theoretically $s = 'apple banana'
    $s = $row['fruits'];
    //  theoretically parts[0]=apple, parts[1]=banana
    $parts = preg_split('/\s+/', $s); 
}
```

Comment: So what is your question? How to do debugging? `var_dump`, `print_r`. Or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP database return values are strings (variants), so `$row["fruits"]` would return a string even if the MySQL datatype was an integer you would still get a valid string. Because PHP is not strongly typed, it does a lot of automatic casting for you meaning you can use results as integers or floats or strings (and interchangeably) in your code.

One final point of note: PHP will return (MySQL)NULL values as an empty string `""`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to try and debug because you're afraid of losing your database :

1) you're gonna have a bad time going on so you should find a way not to jeopardize your data while testing

2) you can try and enforce strings: `$s = (string) $row['fruits'];`  even if it should already be a string